# Auto complete option using jquery and servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

How I can limit the autocomplete using following code

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

Comment: limit what? the size? the options? what? what? WHAAAAAAAT?

Comment: You need to explain your question a little better, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: It would be helpful to know what limits you mean to put on it.  There are many ways to limit an autocomplete.  One of the best ways to make clear what help you want would be to tell us what the code you've presented does, and how that differs from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

I created a separate jsp to iterate and add the source to autocomplete. You can implement it in this way:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete("./getdata.jsp");
```

Code for getdata.jsp looks like:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%

//Assuming the 'availableTags' is iterable List<String>

    Iterator<String> iterator = availableTags.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {

            String source = (String)iterator.next();
            out.println(source);

        }
%>
```